# html5 canvas text slide in behind nothing

Tags: html, canvas, text, slide, effect

I want to have html5 canvas text slide in behind nothing, its an effect where text appears like coming out behind some obstacle, but the obstacle is invisible.
Here is some youtube video showing how to do it in after effect:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIYMy7vLLRo

I know how to slide a text along canvas, and one idea I got is having two canvases on top of each other, and top canvas is smaller and contains the text that is initially out of canvas and slides in. But if there is a way to do it with just one canvas that would be great.

Comment: While sliding your text, you can use `ctx.clearRect()` over the area of the obstacle.

Comment: Woudn't that also clear other stuff drawn on canvas beneath the text?

Comment: yes indeed, if you already have something on your canvas then `clearRect()`  will delete it. I suggest you build a simple version of what you are thinking in a jsfiddle and update your question. You will get better help here if we can see some code.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/vgpov2yk/3

```
var c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// Positions for the text startint off
var xText = -100;
var yText = 150;

// This will update the canvas as fast as possible (not good)
setInterval(function () {
    // Clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F0F";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.save()

    // We create a clip rect 
    ctx.rect(200,0,400,400);
    ctx.clip();

    // Draw text
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World", xText, yText);

    ctx.restore();

    // Increase the text x position
    if (xText < 200) {
        xText += 0.5;
    }

}, 15);
```

All you have to do is use a clip rect which is like a mask in image editing.

Comment: thanks but obscuring rectangle needs to be transparent to have effect of text appear out of nowhere. you wrote black background and black obscuring rectangle. if you have background image on canvas then its complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can using a clipping path to mask out part of the text.

Save the existing clipping path using the save() method. Create a shape/path and make it the new clipping path using the clip() method. Draw your text. Store the previous clipping path using the restore() method.

For example, suppose your canvas is 100 pixels by 100 pixels. The following will draw text on only the left side of the canvas.

```
context.save();
context.rect(0, 0, 50, 100);
context.clip();
context.fillText("Draw some text.", 30, 50);
context.restore();
```